# To iterate by block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, each

I used Ruby on Rails and I have created more of 40 hiraganas flashcards. In my index view, I do an iteration like this. 
Some of Hiraganas cards have different I want to create different columns which host different color cards.

I want to iterate on letter A = green, E = red, I = Pink, etc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tervb.png)

I only do that

```
<% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %>
  <li>
    <%= render 'allhiraganas', hiragana: hiragana %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Do you know how to select only few elements to iterate. I see some tutos but I try `.select`

here is the render flashcards code

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-inline text-center card-frame">
    <li>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
            <%= link_to hiragana_path(hiragana), class:'trash-hiragana', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete do %>
            <%= image_tag("delete-btn.png") %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <!-- PARAMETRER LE RESPONSIVE BOOTSTRAP -->
        <!-- <div class="col-sm- col-xs-4 col-md-3"> -->
          <span class="card-question popover-word" data-content="<h4 class='text-center letter-uppercase'><%= hiragana.bigletter.upcase %></h4><p class='text-center'><b><%= hiragana.midletter %></b> comme dans <b><%= hiragana.transcription %></b></p>">
            <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i>
          </span>

          <!-- son de l'hiragana -->
          <span class="audioclick popover-word" data-content="<p class='text-center'><b>le son arrive prochainement !</b></p>">
            <i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-lg"></i>
          </span>
          <!-- image mnémotechnique -->
          <span class="idea popover-word" data-content="<p class='text-center'><b>l'image est bientôt prête !</b><%= hiragana.upload %></p>">
            <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-lg"></i>
          </span>
          <!-- <div class="prononciation">
            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
          </div> -->

          <div class="card-hiragana hiragana-<%=hiragana.bigletter.downcase.last%>">
            <h1><b><%= hiragana.ideo1 %></b></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="card-katakana">
            <p><%= hiragana.ideo2 %></p>
          </div>
          <div id="favorite_<%=hiragana.id%>">
            <%= render 'favs/favorites', hiragana: hiragana %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-md-3 containerbackcards-<%=hiragana.bigletter.downcase.last%>">
            <div class="backcard-hiragana">
              <h1><b><%= hiragana.ideo1 %></b></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-bigletter">
              <h4><%= hiragana.bigletter.upcase %></h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends: If you have the color saved in the hiragana model, then you just need to:

```
greenhiriganas = Hirigana.where(color: "green")
```

If you just know in your head, which letters have which colors, then for each section you need to write an array containing all the names

```
#if for example A, Ka and Shi are green
green = [:a, :ka, :shi]
#then select via include?-method
greenhiriganas = Hirigana.select{ |hiri| green.include?(hiri.name) }
```

Comment: William no colors actually are saved in my model but in my controller when I create a cards with a letter A, E, I, O, U. Where do I put the code above in the second part code (direct in my view)?

Answer (score 1):

which ones do you want? what's the logic for which you'd like to choose? If you simply wanted the first 3 you could say

```
 @hiriganas = Hirigana.first(3)
```

if you have a condition you'd like to choose them by select is a good choice.

```
 @hiriganas = @hiriganas.select{ |hir|  # criteria for selection }
```

Comment: thank you. I try this but I just ant to list in vertical column card which have the same color. One column with green colour, one with red colour...

Comment: is color a column on the table?

Comment: if you have a column named color try this (add an @ in front of the vars): 

green_hiriganas = Hirigana.where(color: 'green')
red_hiriganas = Hirigana.where(color: 'red')
# etc

then use those variables in the view in the appropriate place you'd like to list

Comment: no. I have just a generator which display the color via the letter I put `hiragana-<%=hiragana.bigletter.downcase.last%> ` and we called the Css class.

Comment: are you saving the letter to the DB?

Comment: @todmetheny Yes The color is save to the DB when I create a card

Comment: @todmetheny here is the code from                                   `hiragana_controller  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :find_hiragana, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @hiraganas = Hiragana.all
  end

  def show
    @alert_message = "Vous avez créé la flashcard #{@hiragana.ideo1}"
  end

  def new
    # if current_user and current_user.admin?
    @hiragana = Hiragana.new
    # else
    #   redirect_to hiraganas_path
    # end
  end`

Comment: `def create
    @hiragana = Hiragana.new(hiragana_params)
    if @hiragana.save
      redirect_to @hiragana
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @hiragana.update(hiragana_params)
      redirect_to @hiragana
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @hiragana.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

private

  def find_hiragana
    @hiragana = Hiragana.find(params[:id])
  end

  def hiragana_params
    params.require(:hiragana).permit(:ideo1, :ideo2, :bigletter, :midletter, :transcription, :upload, :sound, :audioclick)

  end
end`

Comment: hi @BaptisteB. what is the problem you're currently having? The same problem? Is your code on github? Happy to take a look but having trouble understanding how to help.

Comment: I follow you on Github you can have a look on my repository. The problem is i have never used `@hiriganas = @hiriganas.select{ |hir|  # criteria for selection }` I just want to iterate in vertical line by color. Only that. What do I put in  `# criteria for selection`

Comment: # criteria for selection is related to the logic for what you want the colors to be if initially `@hiriganas = Hirigana.all` then `@hirigana = @hirigana.select{ |h| h.color == 'green' }` would return all the green hiriganas. In your case it would be whatever represents the colors you want to return `{ |h| h.bigletter == 4 }` ...that's made up because I don't know what your catalogue system is for the colors. But the criteria for selection should be something that returns true or false. If you want to post a link for the repo I'll take a look.

Comment: here is the repo https://github.com/BaptisteBecmeur/synestasia. Thank you for your help.